# Python re - Extract first word after pattern

Tags: python, regex

Trying to find a pattern "to DestinationLocation" in a massive text blob.
Using the following:

```
pattern = re.compile("to (.*)")
string = #text blob
pattern.search(string)
# When I see the output
>>> _.group(1)
DestinationLocation blah blah blah ...
```

How do I extract only 'DestinatiionLocation' from the captured text?

Comment: Because the DestinationLocation is placeholder for any documented or undocumented location name.

Comment: The word I have to extract comes after "to", it could be any word, so cant  use search.

Comment: So you're looking for a single word that has no particular format but that occurs once after the word "to"? So, `\bto\b.*\b`? How many times does `to` occur in there?

Comment: Could be name of a place or its airport code. like Miami or MIA.

Comment: @Ben : Yes, any first word coming after to, without the following words.

Comment: Can it contain spaces or other special characters? For example, "to North Carolina"?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot : I suppose that will be a seperate logic for names with spaces like 'Los Angeles' , right now I'm targetting single words (plain text) without number/special characters and no spaces for now.

Comment: @Ben : Ideally "to" should only occur once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find a word made only from alphabetic characters, with length of 1 or more, without swallowing following spaces, so use `\w+` (single alpha with length of 1+):

```
pattern = re.compile("to (\w+)")
```

Now, if the word is actually *words* (like `to the mall`) you are going to need some character to indicate the end of the words sequence, like `to the mall.` (dot limiter), and the include space with the available charset, terminating with a dot:

```
pattern = re.compile("to ([\w ]+)\.")
```